# Is there an option to limit daily downloads to WooCommerce subscriptions?

Tags: woocommerce, download, limit, woocommerce-memberships

We have around 150 digital downloadable products powered by WooCommerce and recently had to integrate subscriptions plugin (called WooCommerce subscriptions) and also a WooCommerce memberships plugin. Is there an option to limit 5 downloads per day in subscription.

It is like when the user subscribed to a subscription package, he/she has access to 5 digital downloadable products per day. When reached 5 downloads a day, a quota limit should display them on a page.

like feature I'm seeing it on nobuna at this link
nobuna(dot)com/max-quota-daily/

Answer (score 0):

This plugin will probably do the trick:

https://www.wpdownloadmanager.com/download/download-limit/

Might be best to post this on the Wordpress Stack Exchange :)

Comment: Ruairi, that addon is for WP download manager pro, My store is built with woocommerce, do you have any idea that limits woocommerce digital downloads?